# Windows XP USB HDD Failing to register

Tags: windows-xp, usb

MY sister's PC is failing to register the presence of USB HDD devices when connected to any USB socket. I'm debugging remotely, but apparently "nothing" happens.

She has connected iPods, printers, scanners, webcam, usb thumb drives, card readers, wireless network adapters all fine. Devices that draw power work from the rear sockets.

USB HDD not working from any socket.

The drives tried are borrowed (she wants to back up her work prior to re-formatting, borrowing drives off a friend) and work with no additional power supplies on other machines.

Any ideas where I should start debugging to find out what the problem is?

I have half a suspicion it's jut drive letter conflict, but, she isn't completely useless and says that no device detection bubbles appear or anything, everything else appears to work fine on the PC.

It's a home XPSP2 box, wondering if she's accidentally triggered an MS Security thing to stop people stealing data, but don't know where to start looking for that.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is ask her to try it on another computer to rule out a problem with the drive.

Also, check that the drive does not require an external power source in addition to the USB socket.

Comment: Drive works fine on other machines, and is USB only (I'm told)